# Uncaught TypeError: SocketIOFileUpload is not constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, frontend

I have installed the socketio-file-upload library and imported it as follows:

```
import {SocketIOFileUpload} from "socketio-file-upload";
```

Then I call it according to the following code:

```
     var sifu = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: SocketIOFileUpload is not constructor
```

I am going to make it possible to send photos and files in a chat application using socket.io
my app created by :
node.js
mongoose
express
react